# lightning:combobox component without placeholder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have following code which displays a list of Users in the system. It is showing the list of Users. By default the first option I see is "Select an Option" and I want the first User in the list to be defaulted. Is it possible?

```
<lightning:combobox name="assignedTo" label="Assigned To" 
           aura:id="inputSelectedUser" options="{!v.userList}" required="true" 
           onchange="{!c.setOutputVariables}" />
```

I am getting the result I want using following code. But, combobox looks way better than select

```
<lightning:select aura:id="inputSelectedUser" name="assignedTo" 
           label="Assigned To" onchange="{!c.setOutputVariables}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.userList}" var="aUser">
        <option value="{!aUser.value}">{!aUser.label}</option>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `value` attribute in this case to default to any item in your list.

If you refer to the example in the documentation as below:

```
<lightning:combobox aura:id="selectItem" name="status" label="Status"
                  placeholder="Choose Status"
                  value="new"
                  onchange="{!c.handleOptionSelected}"
                  options="{!v.statusOptions}"/>
```

`placeholder` does not have any impact here as long as `value` is provided. So once you provide the `value` attribute, you can always default it to any required value in your list.

---

So in your case, you can have an attribute declared which gets the first item from your list and then use that there. Something as below:

```
<aura:attribute name="defaultVal" type="String" default=""/>
<lightning:combobox name="assignedTo" label="Assigned To" 
                  value="{!v.defaultVal}"
                  aura:id="inputSelectedUser" options="{!v.userList}" required="true" 
                  onchange="{!c.setOutputVariables}" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! I just had to put in a hack in my helper to populate the "{!v.defaultVal}" but that is the price I am willing to pay to make this work the way I want.

Comment: That's right. You just need to populate that value upfront to be able to use it. Good thing is that at least there's a way to use the `value` attribute.